# Multiple build configurations with qmake and qt pro file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I am using Qt and qmake for some project on Windows.

I use `qmake` to generate visual studio's `.sln` and `.vcproj` files.

There is one problem that I could not solve now. When I use visual studio, I can specify new Project Build Configuration other than debug and release as [How to: Create and Edit Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx) sad, so I can have build configurations like:

- `Debug`
- `Release`
- `DebugFeatureOn`
- `ReleaseFeatureOn`

But when use `qmake`, I can do is set `CONFIG` variable to add new configs, but when run `qmake -tp vc` to generate visual studio project files, vs's Build Configuration only has `debug` and `release`.

So I wonder if there is a way to create new build configuration using `qmake`.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between `Debug` and `DebugFeatureOn`?

Comment: @svlasov, some different macro define , different libs linked.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for your question please?