# Qt5 is it possible to define more than one build configuration?

Tags: qt, qmake

I am working on application for Mac OS written in C++ using Qt5.7.1, which is distributed both as direct download from website and through App Store.

Now I have a new requirement to add self-update to the application. Which would require building two different versions of application - one for App Store (without self-update mechanism) and one for direct download (with self-update).

I have no problem to implement the self-update, but I am stuck with making a separate build configuration. So the question is -- **in Qt5 is it possible to define two separate Release configurations (in a single `.pro` file) and if yes, then how?** It also needs to work with `qmake` since the builds are automatic (with Jenkins).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405899/multiple-build-configurations-with-qmake-and-qt-pro-file

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really define 2 **Release** configurations in a .pro file.

However you can define different configuration options in your .pro file like this:

```
foo {
    #something
    DEFINES += FOO
} else {
    #something else
    DEFINES += NOT_FOO
}

bar {
    #another thing
    DEFINES += BAR=42
}
```

And then when you run `qmake`, add either `CONFIG+=foo` or `CONFIG+=bar` or both.

Finally in QtCreator you can define as many build profile as you want and customize the call to qmake for each profile by adding or not `CONFIG+=foo` options.

For more information check qmake's `CONFIG` [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#config), especially the last example.

Comment: _You cannot really define 2 Release configurations in a .pro file_
does this not contradict your second sentence?

What you said is right. The easiest way is to copy your release-config in qt creator, and then add CONFIG-flags to the qmake command depending on which kind of release you build. That said you can have an unlimited number of "release"/"debug" configurations.

Comment: @markus-nm That's why there is "really" and "release" is in bold. If you take the question in bold literally, the answer is "no".